# Django: URL template tag leads to 404, but correct when hard coded

Tags: python, django

Going through polls tutorial modifying it to make a blog. (Django 1.6)

In index.html I can get a hyperlink to lead to the correct URL when it's hard coded like so:

```
<h2><a href="/blog/{{ entry.id }}/">{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
```

But when I use the URL template tag, I get a 404 (I namespaced blog in the project urls.py)

```
<h2><a href="{$ url 'blog:detail' entry.id %}/">{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
```

The 404 page I get passes raw Django code into the URL

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/%7B$%20url%20'blog:detail'%20entry.id%20%%7D/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^polls/
^blog/ ^$ [name='index']
^blog/ ^(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$ [name='detail']
^blog/ ^(?P<entry_id>\d+)/comment/$ [name='comment']
^admin/
The current URL, blog/{$ url 'blog:detail' entry.id %}/, didn't match any of these.
```

Here's urls.py in the blog app

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<entry_id>\d+)/comment/$', views.comment, name='comment'),
)
```

And here are the relevant views:

```
def index(request):
    latest_entries = Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    tags = Tags.objects.filter()
    context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries, 'tags': tags}
    return render(request, 'entries/index.html', context)

def detail(request, entry_id):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=entry_id)
    return render(request, 'entries/detail.html', {'entry': entry})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `{$` to `{%`:

```
<h2><a href="{% url 'blog:detail' entry.id %}/">{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
```

Comment: we had almost same timing xD

Comment: I thought I messed up copying my code to Stack Overflow when I saw your response, but yep, that was it. You made me realize my monitor is too far away. Thanks to you and @markcial

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your template tag, instead of

```
{$ url 'blog:detail' entry.id %}
```

write

```
{% url 'blog:detail' entry.id %}
```

take care with dollar signs and use percent ones